# with regards to TDA rules about reraise

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

we had a situation playing poker (home game)
SB: 5
BB: 10
Position 3: bets 50
Position 5: reraise to 250
Position 7: allin 500

question: Can position 5 reraise when its his turn?

Answer (score 1):

Yes #5 can reraise, since #7 made a full raise, it does reopen the action, the general rule is that a raise of half the previous bet or more is considered a full bet for purposes of reopening the action when a player raises all in, in this case specifically, all that 7 needed to raise to reopen the action was 100, which is half the previous raise made, by P-5. this rule may vary between different card rooms.
I don't know exactly what the TDA rule is, perhaps you can look it up

Comment: I've been out of the game for a while, but I believe the TDA rule was full raise required to re-open the action, not just half-raise. But this raise would be good either way.

Comment: Not exactly relevant to the question, but thanks.